# Deconstruct tuples in lambda expressions

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility to access the elements of a tuple directly in a deconstructed way in the argument list of a lambda expression like in the following snippet?

```
Func<(int A, int B), int> f = ((a, b)) => a + b;
```

What works fine is decomposing the tuple inside the body:

```
Func<(int, int), int> f = i => i.Item1 + i.Item2;
```

Comment: I don;t think so, but `Func<(int A, int B), int> f = (x) => x.A + x.B;` is at least a bit nicer.